# why defer statement works differently when annoymouse function returned

Tags: go, defer-keyword

here i declare a function which defer trace1

```golang
func TestDeferFunc(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("start", time.Now())
    defer trace1()
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
}

func trace1() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("end time: ", startTime)
    fmt.Println("execute time: ", time.Since(startTime))
}
```

after run `go test -run=^TestDeferFunc$`,below is what i got

```
start 2019-11-26 12:50:59.59489797 +0800 CST m=+0.000202866
end time:  2019-11-26 12:51:02.595090951 +0800 CST m=+3.000395880
execute time:  49.065µs
```

howerver, when i defer another annoymouse function, things changed

```golang
func TestDeferFunc(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("start", time.Now())
    defer trace2()()
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
}

func trace2() func() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("end time: ", startTime)
    fmt.Println("execute time: ", time.Since(startTime))
    return func() {
        fmt.Println("zzz")
    }
}
```

below is the `go test` result

```
start 2019-11-26 12:52:58.318472958 +0800 CST m=+0.000197852
end time:  2019-11-26 12:52:58.318554368 +0800 CST m=+0.000279262
execute time:  4.853µs
zzz
```

could someone help me out! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `defer` statement only `defer`s the evaluated function call - and the function call is evaluated at the time `defer` execuated. As per doc:

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked. Instead, deferred functions are invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the reverse order they were deferred. That is, if the surrounding function returns through an explicit return statement, deferred functions are executed after any result parameters are set by that return statement but before the function returns to its caller. If a deferred function value evaluates to nil, execution panics when the function is invoked, not when the "defer" statement is executed.

Your code `defer trace2()()` essentially is equlavent of `f := trace2(); defer f()`. So `trace2` gets evaluated (and thus called) immediately.

So to achieve what you might want (tracing time), you may use `defer trace3()()` with `trace3()` like this:

```
func trace3() func() {
    startTime := time.Now()

    return func() {
        fmt.Println("end time: ", time.Now())
        fmt.Println("execute time: ", time.Since(startTime))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to trace time with defer is to pass the start time to the deferred function:

```golang
func trace1(startTime time.Time) {
    fmt.Println("start", startTime)
    fmt.Println("end time: ", time.Now())
    fmt.Println("execute time: ", time.Since(startTime))
}

func TestDeferFunc(t *testing.T) {
    defer trace1(time.Now())
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
}
```

The parameters passed are executed immediately, but the actual function call is deferred to the end.

If you want to be more explicit about what is executed and what is deferred, you can wrap the whole thing in a function so that you are sure everything inside is executed at the end

```
defer func() {
    ..... code ....
}()
```